# How to get scene statistics in python, when Blender is in Edit mode

Tags: python, vertices

I am trying to get my hand on the total number of rendered vertices in the 3DView (so, taking modifiers into considerations).
I can do that by iterating through all the objects in the scene, creating bmeshes out of them and then count the bmesh verts... but I can see that a way faster solution, which is to extract the vertex count from the scene statistics.

Here is the command to get that:

`stats = context.scene.statistics(context.view_layer)`

It would return something like this for my current scene:

> Collection | Cube.002 | Verts:33,751 | Faces:31,327 | Tris:61,158 | Objects:1/137 | Memory: 1.13 GiB | 3.2.1

This is a great solution. But here is my problem, **it does not work when Blender is in Edit mode**. When blender is in edit mode, the statistics will return the stats from the selected objects only.
In the same scene as the previous, it would return this:

> Cube.002 | Verts:4/8 | Edges:4/12 | Faces:1/6 | Tris:12 | Objects:1/137 | Memory: 1.13 GiB | 3.2.1

I really need to get the stats of the **entire scene**.
I tried switching the mode to object by using `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')`, I also tried setting the active object to `None` and then calling `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`, but it does not output the statistics of the entire scene... at best it stopped showing the selected verts "4/" and only the total of the verts of the selected object.

Comment: You can do something like `sum(len(o.data.polygons) for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == "MESH")`. I don't know about the performance if you have thousands of objects though

Comment: It's actually more work, since I want the vertex count including the modifiers, it becomes something like:
`for object in scene_meshes:

current_bmesh=bmesh.new()

current_bmesh.from_object(object,context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(), cage=False, 
   face_normals=False, vertex_normals=False)

current_bmesh.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

max_vertex_count+= len(current_bmesh.verts)

current_bmesh.free()`
Like I wrote in the question, I am looking for something faster/lighter. The statistics of the entire scene are right there, but I can't access it...

Comment: you don't need to use bmesh here I think, just use the evaluated data from the depsgraph https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html. The statistics of the entire scene are not AFAIK available while in edit mode precisely for performance reasons. Otherwise you can for instance add a custom prop to your scene, update it every time you go into object mode and poll this property when you need it

Comment: Ah yes right, `max_vertex_count=sum(len(obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph).data.vertices) for obj in context.scene.objects)` That looks a lot less wasteful than using bmesh.
Thank you for your answer! And for the explanation about the scene stats.